# Append Data to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I did a code in which I pick P-wave seismic waveform, basically is a time pick along waveform, also compute the signal-to-noise and other variables.

Here is part of my code.

```
for tr in st:
    tr_cut = tr.trim(A, B) #cut the waveform from A to B section
#Here starts to compute the P time, Signal-to-noise, etc    
    scnl, picks, polarity, snr, uncert = picker.picks(tr_cut)
    all_ = []
for i in range(len(picks)):
    print (scnl, picks[i], polarity, snr, uncert) # this is the output
# Here I try to append the data inside a DataFrame
    all_.append(
        {
            'scnl': scnl,
            'picks': picks[i],
            'snr': snr,
            'polarity': polarity,
            'uncert': uncert
         }
     )
     pd.DataFrame(all_)
```

But I am not being able to append the output from the function I specify here

> scnl, picks, polarity, snr, uncert = picker.picks(tr_cut)

However if I print the output of the function I get the results

> print (scnl, picks[i], polarity, snr, uncert)
> gives an output like this:

```
BBOJ.SHZ.BO., UTCDateTime(2020, 11, 10, 13, 9, 59, 200000), '', 8.1999993, 0.02 
BBOD.SHZ.BO., UTCDateTime(2020, 11, 10, 13, 10, 4, 260000), 'D', 9.5, 0.02 
BBOB.SHZ.BO., UTCDateTime(2020, 11, 10, 13, 10, 7, 620000), 'C', 8.90004, 0.040000
```

The aim of my idea is to append all this output inside the DataFrame but I can not do it. Moreover  while I try to convert my DataFrame to CSV I get the following error.

> 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Would you mind give me feedback what I am doing wrong, thank you
Tonino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I modified a little the code with @Deep suggestions.

```
all_ = []
for tr in st:
    tr_cut = tr.trim(A, B) #cut the waveform from A to B section
#Here starts to compute the P time, Signal-to-noise, etc    
    scnl, picks, polarity, snr, uncert = picker.picks(tr_cut)
   
for i in range(len(picks)):
    print (scnl, picks[i], polarity, snr, uncert) # this is the output
# Here I try to append the data inside a DataFrame
    all_.append(
        {
            'scnl': scnl,
            'picks': picks[i],
            'snr': snr,
            'polarity': polarity,
            'uncert': uncert
         }
     )
     df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_, orient='columns')
     df.to_csv("Picks.csv")
```

Moving the variable `all_ = []` outside of the first loop solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

While appending are you getting any errors or is it simply not working? With current information, it seems doing following shall solve your issue:

You have to assign your dataframe to some variable (say `df`). Also, it looks like you will want to create dataframe after you have finished iterating over `all_`. If that's the case, you need to do following assignment *outside* for loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_)
```

About your second error, it seems you had tried `all_.to_csv()`. Since `all_` is a list, `to_csv` would not work. You will probably want to do `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: I got no errors, I got and empty DataFrame. you were right about df.to_csv(all_) however it is empty csv file too

Comment: try `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_, orient='columns')`, did it work?

Comment: same results I have an empty DataFrame, do you think moving all_=[] outside of the first for loop will help?

Comment: it worked taking out `all = []` now I have the DataFrame with information

Comment: I was trying to reproduce error but couldn't, glad it is working now!